# Effective grep of log file

Tags: regex, logging, grep

I have a log file with a lot of lines on this format:

```
10.87.113.12 - - [2019-12-09T11:41:07.197Z] "DELETE /page/sub1.php?id=alice HTTP/1.1" 401 275 "-" "alice/7.61.1"
10.87.113.12 - - [2019-12-09T11:41:07.197Z] "DELETE /page/sub1.php?id=alice HTTP/1.1" 401 275 "-" "alice/7.61.1"
10.87.113.12 - - [2019-12-09T11:43:51.008Z] "POST /page/sub2.php?id=alice&jw_token=07e876afdc2245b53214fff0d4763730 HTTP/1.1" 200 275 "-" "alice/7.61.1"
```

My objective is simple: I want to output Alice's jw_token, and that's it.

So, my logic is that I need to find the lines that include `id=alice` and a status code of 200, then return the value of `jw_token`.

I actually managed to do this, but only with this absolute monstrosity of a line:

```sh
$ grep "id=alice" main.log | grep 200 | grep -o "n=.* " | sed "s/.*=//g" | sed "s/ .*$//g" | uniq
07e876afdc2245b53214fff0d4763730
```

This looks horrible, and may also break on a number of things (for instance if "200" happens to appear anywhere else on the line). I know `grep -P` could have cleaned it up somewhat, but unfortunately that flag isn't available on my Mac.

I also did it by including Python, like this:

```py
cat << EOF > analyzer.py
import re

with open('main.log') as f:
    for line in f:
        if "id=alice" in line and " 200 " in line:
            print(re.search('(?<=jw_token\=).*?(?=\s)', line).group())
            break
EOF
python3 analyzer.py && rm analyzer.py
```

(This was actually MUCH (orders of magnitude) faster than the previous line with `grep` and `sed`. Why?)

Surely there are ways to make this a lot cleaner and prettier. How?

Comment: How about `grep " 200 "`?

Comment: Thank you, @RedCricket. That would fix one of the breaking points. However, it wouldn't make the code any prettier. Still in search of some awesome solution.

Comment: Looks pretty to me. Beauty is in the eye of the beholder

Comment: are you open to calling a python script? a short (although >1 line) python script could parse the log as you desire and the code would be clearer than grep/awk from sh

Comment: @Max OP says **effective**

Comment: I have updated the question to include my Python-in-bash solution. To my surprise, this is actually much, much faster than the grep+sed line. Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using just one grep and sed with this command,

```
grep -E 'id=alice&jw_token=.* HTTP\/1.1" 200' main.log|sed -E 's/.*id=alice&jw_token=([a-zA-Z0-9]+).*/\1/'|uniq
```

Here first part `grep -E 'id=alice&jw_token=.* HTTP\/1.1" 200' main.log` will filter out all lines not having alice and not having status 200 and next `sed -E 's/.*id=alice&jw_token=([a-zA-Z0-9]+).*/\1/'` part will just capture the token in group1 and replace whole line with just the token.

Comment: The last code works perfectly. Thank you!
(The first one spits out a huge amount of false positives)

Comment: @genbatro: Yes I guessed that which is why I added second one so the grep already filters out everything not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, this should be an easy task for `awk` in case you are ok with `awk`.

```
awk '
/alice/ && match($0,/jw_token=[^ ]* HTTP\/1\.1\" 200/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART+9,RLENGTH-9)
  split(val,array," ")
  print array[1]
  delete array
}'  Input_file
```

Comment: OP says their grep doesn't have -P flag. And `cut` is redundant anyways, `\K[[:xdigit:]]*` would handle that

Comment: @oguzismail, yeah just added  in case of GNU `grep` thats why my first attempt was `awk` :) Let me remove it now(grep one) :)

Comment: Okay. However, OP wants to select lines where HTTP response code is 200, to filter out invalid jw_tokens obviously. Both solutions you posted ignore that

Comment: @oguzismail, Thanks for saving the day, I changed it now, need a coffee :) Thanks you buddy :)

Comment: Where do I put "alice" in this code? Right now it finds almost all lines, and returns more than the jw_token too:
```
72744e82e257e1928ba4328727b0426d&page=549
d64cc42f98bb8314452514778f94a9cf&page=348
10cde18599fd5b7992d6e76b3d957f0c&id=z564s6trr
845ba55d44d36d4734d37b2886fc9478&id=8rphr3ij6
a6ada4c28a8a8112a857ab1cb1740abc&id=8p5ui1p5r
```

Comment: @genbatro, ok, to search string alice I added  it in regex can you please try and lemme know then?

Answer (score 0):

Would you try the following:

```
grep "id=alice.* 200 " main.log | sed 's/.*jw_token=\([^ ]\{1,\}\).*/\1/' | uniq
```

Comment: This does indeed find the relevant lines, but prints all the lines, and the whole line. I'd like to have just the token. Thank you for answering!

Comment: @genbatro Thank you for the feedback. I had to tweak the sed command to work on MacOS. Would you please test my updated code? Sorry for bothering you. BR.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to a perl oneliner:

```
perl -ane '/id=alice&jw_token=([a-f0-9]+).+\b200\b/ && $h{$1}++;END{print"$_\n" for sort(keys %h)}' file.txt
07e876afdc2245b53214fff0d4763730
```

**Explanation:**

```
/                           # regex delimiter
    id=alice&jw_token=      # literally
    ([a-f0-9]+)             # group 1, 1 or more hexa
    .+                      # 1 or more any character
    \b200\b                 # 200 surrounded with word boundaries
/                           # regex delimiter, you may use /i for case insensitive
```

Comment: Works very well, thank you. Only needs to sort out the duplicates and return one unique token.